# Why Bootstrap's size classes stop working at 5?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For example: `<div class="container m-5">` works perfectly, but `<div class="container m-9">` doesn't. It seems any number beyond 5 no longer works. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you are right. There are only `m-1, m-2, m-3, m-4, m-5` classes in bootstrap 4+. if you want to give more margin then give another m-5 class in its child div like `<div class="container m-5"><div class="subcontainer m-5">`
See this [Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 includes only five-level scale for spacing utilities not beyond 5. [Check here for documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/utilities-for-layout/#margin-and-padding).

```
.m-1{ margin: .25rem!important}
.m-2{ margin: .5rem!important}
.m-3{ margin: 1rem!important}
.m-4{ margin: 1.5rem!important}
.m-5{ margin: 3rem!important}
```